# EF Mapping column not using a PK

Tags: entity-framework

I have a relationship between 2 tables that the column in the second table is not the PK. How can I

map this using EF 6 and fluent API?

There is an example:

[image: Tables Example]

```
// Fluent API Relationship
this.HasRequired(t => t.Product)
    .WithMany(t => t.Product_Assurance_Procedure)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.Assurance_ID);
```

I am trying to fill a property collection of Product_Assurance_Procedure inside Product class using "Include" command. But the Sql script genereted by EF is using the wrong column inside the join:

```
...
FROM  [dbo].[Product] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Product_Assurance_Procedure] AS [Extent2] ON
    [Extent1].[Assurance_ID] = [Extent2].[Product_Assurance_Procedure_ID]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post your models as well?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
from p in Product
join pap in Product_Assurance_Procedure on p.Assurance_ID equals pap.Assurance_ID
select p
```

I was trying to use "Include" but don't work probably because bad relationship configuration...